# Rifinements or monkey patching rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I am using rail4 and ruby 2.0, I want to add a method **"first_error"** in **ActiveModel::Errors** that should be available throughout my application, So i came across following 2 possibilities :

- Monkey Patch
- Refinement

I has successfully implemented the first approach just by creating an initializer "custom_model_error.rb"

```
class ActiveModel::Errors
  def first_error
    if !self.first
      return nil
    end
    data = Hash.new
    data['error_code'] = '900'
    data['message'] = self.first.join(' ')
    return data
  end
end
```

But when i tried to implement the second approach by defining a module in lib directory:

```
  module RefineErrors
    refine ActiveModel::Errors do
      def first_error
        if !self.first
          return nil
        end
        data = Hash.new
        data['error_code'] = '900'
        data['message'] = self.first.join(' ')
        return data
      end
    end
  end
```

and then using this module in ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
   using RefineErrors
```

i get the error **undefined method 'using'**.

Now my questions are:

**which is the best approach to implement at present**? 
Monkey Patching is generally not recommended, and refinements is the experimental feature of ruby 2.0

Also want to know **how to implement this using refinements in rails4**?

If there is any other approach that should be followed in this scenario, please mention that also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ruby 2.0, you need to use patch of ruby which support refinements.take a look at here http://timelessrepo.com/refinements-in-ruby
This links also share the power of monkey patching and refinements.

Comment: Thanks for help Ashutosh, Please go through the code, i think i am implementing it the same way as described in the link, but as i mentioned earlier i am getting **undefined method `using' for ApplicationController:Class (NoMethodError)** error when using 'using' keyword inside ApplicationController.

Comment: Please check installing section of above link.problem is that the you are using default patch of ruby 2.0(might be 481, which does not support it properly),you need to add the specific patch which was mentioned in installing section of above link.if you try to do above with ruby 2.1 you won't get an error.